# Unity attach script to enemy object, instead my player affected

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to enemy fire at me. I have a script and I attached script to enemy object. However, unexpectedly my player object fire non stop instead of enemy.I dont know how my player object affected.Also distance is not calculated properly. it shows 1000, then 1200 then 800 etc.

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class shten : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject AntagonisticElement;
    public GameObject Target;
    public float bulletSpeed;
    public float enemySpeed;
    public float bulletDestroyTime;
    public GameObject explsn;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public Transform bulletSpawn;

    Vector3 pos;
    public float dist;
    public float min = 200;
    public float max = 150;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        dist = Vector3.Distance(AntagonisticElement.transform.position, Target.transform.position);
        transform.LookAt(Target.transform.position);

        if (dist >= min)
        {
            AntagonisticElement.transform.position += AntagonisticElement.transform.forward * 4 * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (dist <= max)
        {
            shootAt();
        }
    }

    void shootAt()
    {
        Instantiate(explsn, bulletSpawn.transform.position, bulletSpawn.transform.rotation);
        var bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletSpawn.position, bulletSpawn.rotation);
        bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = bullet.transform.forward * bulletSpeed;

        Destroy(bullet, bulletDestroyTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what are the values of `bulletSpawn`, `Target` and `AntagonisticElement`?

Comment: btw `shootAt()` is called everytime if the distance is small enough ... it's probably not a good idea to instantiate a bullet in every frame

Comment: target is my player object, antelement is enemy tank , bulletspawn is tank Bullet

Comment: from the variable names in the script I get what their purpose but can you make sure they are all asigned correctly?

Comment: Are you sure that BulletSpawn is where you want in your scene AND that you put the correct object in the BulletSpawn variable in the editor?